# How to improve magnification and rotation gesture recogniser methods in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

I'm playing with NSGestureRecognizer(s) in Objective-C.
I have a simple Custom View in the XIB canvas to which I applied the press, pan, magnify, and rotate gesture recognisers. From each one I have created an action in AppDelegate.m and then added code to it. They all work to some extent but the way magnify and rotate behave does not satisfy me.
Here is the code for both of them:

```
- (IBAction)magnifyView:(NSMagnificationGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGFloat magnification = sender.magnification + 1.0;
    NSView *view = sender.view;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(magnification, magnification);
    [[view layer] setAffineTransform:transform];
    sender.magnification = 0;
}
```

and ...

```
- (IBAction)rotateView:(NSRotationGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGFloat rotation = sender.rotation;
    NSView *view = sender.view;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);
    [[view layer] setAffineTransform:transform];
    sender.rotation = 0;
}
```

I'm using a 2016 MBP with macOS 12.4 and Xcode 13.4.1 to realise this and, using the trackpad for the gestures, I see that `magnifyView` seems to stutter unless I strongly open my fingers in an "unpinch" gesture—which risks triggering the macOS show desktop, while `rotateView` only rotates of a few degrees before coming back.

The whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/Cellomaster87/Apple-Programming-YT/tree/main/Cocoa%20Programming/Cocoa%20Pr%20L64%20NSGestureRecognizer), if you feel like giving it a look. It doesn't contain much else anyway, it's an experiment.
Could you please give it a look (or even just at the methods above) and tell me what I could do to improve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Tip: log `magnification` and `rotation`.

Comment: Thanks. For `magnification` I was consistently getting values of up to 1.35 or around that, no more. Small pinch gestures produced 1/1000th increments. 
For `rotation` all values were in the order of 100th or 1000th, so between 0.002 and 0.03. Is there something I am missing in how things should be configured?